# QT QML ListView - centralised highlight bar with enlarged text

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I'm attempting to implement a 5 line centralised menu using ListView. The text in the highlighted position needs to be larger than the other menu items and should transition smoothly as the menu is scrolled. Ideally there should be 3 different text sizes - central biggest, items next to central slightly smaller and items on the outside even smaller, but just bigger text for the central item is ok.

When menu stops scrolling the centralised item needs to scroll horizontally if bigger than the screen width.

This is for an embedded device that has a rotary encoder for menu navigation. setIndex() is used to set the menu position.

The following code works ok when scrolling slowly but gets a bit confused when scrolling faster. Items outwith the central bar sometimes go big etc.

Seems like a problem that should have already been solved but I can't find an example anywhere.

Here is the code -

```
import QtQuick 1.1

// Menu
// 5 line menu, highlight bar centralised


Rectangle {
    id: window
    color: "#00000000"
    property int numLines: 5
    property alias menuIndex: listView.currentIndex
    property int lineHeight: window.height/window.numLines
    property alias model: listView.model
    clip: true

    function setIndex(iIndex) {
        var displayedIndex = Math.round((listView.contentY/window.lineHeight +   Math.floor(numLines/2)));
        //console.log("MENU2: " + displayedIndex + " " + iIndex + " " + Math.abs(displayedIndex - iIndex));

        // If we're too far behind current index jump straight to it rather than leaving it to smooth scroll
        if (Math.abs(displayedIndex - iIndex) > 15)
          listView.positionViewAtIndex(iIndex, ListView.Center);

        listView.currentIndex = iIndex
    }     

    function setItemSelected(bSelected) {
        scrollingText.setItemSelected(bSelected);
    } 

    // Define a delegate component.  A component will be
    // instantiated for each visible item in the list.
    Component {
        id: menuItemDelegate

        Item {
            id:wrapper
            height: window.height/window.numLines
            width: window.width

            Text {id: wrapperText; text: menuText; width: window.width; height: window.height/window.numLines; font.pixelSize: (wrapper.height * 3)/4; color: "white"; horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter; verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter}

            states: [
                State {
                    name: "Current"
                    when: wrapper.ListView.isCurrentItem
                    PropertyChanges { target: wrapper; scale: 1.0 }
                    PropertyChanges { target: scrollingText; currentText: menuText }
                    PropertyChanges { target: scrollingText; scrollStart: true }
                },
                State {
                    name: "NotCurrent"
                    when: wrapper.ListView.isCurrentItem == 0
                    PropertyChanges { target: wrapper; scale: 0.7 }
                }               
            ]

            transitions: Transition {
                ParallelAnimation 
                {             
                    NumberAnimation { properties: "scale"; duration: 100 } 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Highlight bar
    Image {id: highlightBar;      y: 2 * window.lineHeight; height: lineHeight; width:window.width; source: "Menu_HighlightBar.png"; scale: 1; opacity:1}

    // Scrolling text that pops up on top of highlight bar area
    Menu2ScrollingText {id: scrollingText;   x:0; z:1;     y: 2 * window.lineHeight; height: lineHeight; width: window.width}

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: window
        //model: cppMenuModel
        delegate: menuItemDelegate
        highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue"; opacity: 0 } // not visible         
        highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true
        preferredHighlightBegin: highlightBar.y
        preferredHighlightEnd: preferredHighlightBegin + window.lineHeight
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
        currentIndex: 0
    }
}
```